# Why did this python script corrupt my excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I run the code below once every day. It was running fine for a few weeks until my excel file randomly got corrupted. I was able to recover it but want to stop it happening again in the future. The script reads in the excel file from yesterday, `df_old`, then appends data calculated from today in `df_merged` and writes it to the excel file. Is there anything here that could have led to a file corruption? I noticed that it said 0 KB for the file after it was corrupted when it was about 700 KB before corruption.

```
df_old = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Python Scripts\mat_flow\reblend_v2.xlsx')
df_merged = pd.concat([df_old, df_merged])
with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Python Scripts\mat_flow\reblend_v2.xlsx', engine="openpyxl", mode="w") as writer:
    df_merged.to_excel(writer, index=False)
```

Edit: `df_merged` is created from an SQL query against a database, with some data transformation done inside Python. `df_merged` is sometimes blank as get_data pulls zero data for that day. However, this shouldnn't cause a problem as appending an empty dataframe to `df_old` should just give back `df_old` unchanged right? I'm thinking the problem could be with not using `with` to read the old excel file. Could this be it?

```
Query=""  #blanked out

cur.execute(Query)
get_data = [data for data in cur]  #pulls data from database
#some data processing done on get_data

df_merged = pd.DataFrame(get_data)
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. There is no way we can be expected to guess what happened with this little information. That said, keep backups and have a process that lets you verify that things worked properly before continuing. Also consider using a plainer data format, such as `.csv`, if feasible. That will make it easier to verify manually what happened with the file (since you can easily examine it in an ordinary text editor, even if it is "corrupted").

Comment: We need more information to find out what really happened, but one potential issue is that you are overwriting your old file with a new file. During this overwriting there is a period where the data only exist in the memory, not on the disk. If there is an error the data will be lost. It will be more robust to write the data to a new file, check if it worked and then potentially remove the old file and rename the new file. That way the old file always remains as backup.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Added a few details

Comment: @AlfredRodenboog Thanks, do you know what type of issues could cause the error whilst writing to disk? I was thinking maybe I ought to use a context manager like ```with``` when I open ```df_old``` but not sure if this is even a possible cause

Comment: it hard to say what makes problem. It can be even problem with hardware - maybe hard drive has bad sectors, or RAM has some defect, or maybe there was voltage surge.

Comment: @furas Do you know whether it's possible it could be me not using ```'with``` to open ```df_old``` though? Or is that unlikely to cause corruption

Comment: using `with` can be safer because it automatically close file - and when you don't close then it may not send data to file on disk because many systems use buffers and when you write in file then it sends it only to buffer, and when you close then it sends from buffer to disk - and when you don't close then it may not send buffer to disk and you may get empty string.